# Low coolant sensor light doesn't turn on

Tags: chevrolet, coolant, sensor, silverado, coolant-reservoir

My '04 Chevy Silverado recently had a coolant leak, and I never received a warning light or dashboard message. I tried unplugging the sensor and still nothing showed up. I tried plugging into a new tank that was empty, still nothing. What could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Did you look in the owner's manual? Does the '04 Silverado have a coolant level sensor? Many vehicles, perhaps most, do not.

Comment: I did. It should come up on DIC.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - Yes, it does.

Comment: I think most coolant level sensors use a ground (low level detected) when the sensor closes, sending a ground signal to the body control module(?) to turn on the low coolant indicator. The sensor may be a sealed magnetic reed switch for lifetime use. Checking continuity on both wires may be necessary since the replacement tank didn't solve this problem. Corroded connections?